# Excel Function - Filter data on specific worksheet using dropdown to select worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to filter the data from specific worksheet when I select from dropdown menu which will be specific month from January to December.

When select specific month e.g. April:

[image]

Then print the data below which then sorted by Column E

[image]

The formula I am currently using is:

```
=LET(baseData,VSTACK(April:May!A2:D5),
baseCrew,VSTACK(April:May!Q2:Z5),
fBaseData,FILTER(baseData,CHOOSECOLS(baseData,1)<>""),
fBaseCrew,FILTER(baseCrew,CHOOSECOLS(baseData,1)<>""),
result1,HSTACK(fBaseData,BYROW(fBaseCrew,LAMBDA(r,FILTER(April!Q1:Z1,r=$A$1,"no result")))),
FILTER(result1,CHOOSECOLS(result1,5)<>"no result"))
```

This print the data from all the worksheets from January - December when selecting Crew Initial:

[image]

Is there a way to improve this to achieve the result above?

Thank you in advance.

---

List Sheet

| INITITAL | MONTH |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AG | JANUARY |  |  |  |
| GH | FEBRUARY |  |  |  |
| ML | MARCH |  |  |  |
| SM | APRIL |  |  |  |
| RP | MAY |  |  |  |
|  | JUNE |  |  |  |
|  | JULY |  |  |  |
|  | AUGUST |  |  |  |
|  | SEPTEMBER |  |  |  |
|  | OCTOBER |  |  |  |
|  | NOVEMBER |  |  |  |
|  | DECEMBER |  |  |  |

---

Data Sheet (April Month - Each month have its own sheet)

| DAY | DATE | MONTH | VENUE | CODE | INVOICE | ORDER NO. | VALUE | PROFIT | EXTRA | INITIAL | NO. | TYPE | VEHICLE | CREW REQ. | INSTALLATION TIME | CREW 1 | CREW 2 | CREW 3 | CREW 4 | CREW 5 | CREW 6 | CREW 7 | CREW 8 | CREW 9 | CREW 10 | INFO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thursday | 6th | April | London | LND0001 | 5000 | 11001 | 2000 | 3000 | 0 | OG | 1 | LOW | VAN | 3 | 1 | ML | SM | AG |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Friday | 7th | April | Birmingham | BRUM0001 | 2450 | 11002 | 4450 | 2000 | 0 | OG | 2 | LOW | VAN | 4 | 2 | SM | ML | GH | RP |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Monday | 20th | April | London | LDN0001 | 4000 | 11003 | 1000 | 3000 | 0 | OG | 3 | LOW | VAN | 3 | 1 | GH | SM | ML |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

---

Report Sheet, when selecting month from the dropdown (A1). It would then print the report from April sheet.

| April |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| DAY | DATE | MONTH | VENUE | CREW | CREW NO |
| Thursday | 6th | April | London | AG | CREW 3 |
| Friday | 7th | April | Birmingham | GH | CREW 3 |
| Monday | 20th | April | London | GH | CREW 1 |
| Thursday | 6th | April | London | ML | CREW 1 |
| Friday | 7th | April | Birmingham | ML | CREW 2 |
| Monday | 20th | April | London | ML | CREW 3 |
| Thursday | 6th | April | London | SM | CREW 2 |
| Friday | 7th | April | Birmingham | SM | CREW 1 |
| Monday | 20th | April | London | SM | CREW 2 |
| Friday | 7th | April | Birmingham | RP | CREW 4 |

Comment: Where does the selection of the month happen; is that always 1 month, or are multiple possible? Could you update your question to include actual data (using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and explain what you expect to happen and where you're currently stuck?

Comment: Please post your input data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format. It helps us to reproduce the scenario and help you to gain more attraction to your question.

Comment: @P.b the month selection are from different sheets within the worksheet which ranged from January - December

Comment: The above formular output the report from all the sheets from January - December sheets when selecting specific Crew Initial, the month name is what I am trying to achieve (when selecting the month name, it will output all the data within that month sheet)

Comment: I just tried it and I got `#CALC!`

Comment: I have run the debug on the formular: `=LET(_baseData, VSTACK(April:May!A2:D5),_baseCrew,VSTACK(April:May!Q2:Z5)` after this formular it then go 0,0,0,0 and so on

Comment: I have changed this formular to 1  `FILTER(_tempOutput,(INDEX(_tempOutput,,3)` and it output the first 3 lines of data but no CREW or CREW NO.

Comment: Sorry the given formula and the expected outputs are different, the given formula doesnt return what you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry If my  explanation isn't clear.

Comment: @TK4795 wait I am updating my answer, I have understood what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then the following formula should work to accomplish the desired output.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _baseData, VSTACK(April:May!A2:D5),
     _baseCrew, VSTACK(April:May!Q2:Z5),
     _fBaseData, FILTER(_baseData,TAKE(_baseData,,1)<>""),
     _fBaseCrew, FILTER(_baseCrew,TAKE(_baseData,,1)<>""),
     _fBaseCrewN, HSTACK(_fBaseData,BYROW(_fBaseCrew,LAMBDA(r,FILTER(April!Q1:Z1,r=$A$1,"no result")))),
     _tempOutput, HSTACK(WRAPCOLS(TOCOL(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(_fBaseCrewN)),
                  LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,IF(_fBaseCrew<>"",INDEX(_fBaseCrewN,,y),NA())))),1),2),
                  SUM(N(_fBaseCrew<>""))),TOCOL(IFS(_fBaseCrew<>"",_fBaseCrew),2)),
     _output, SORT(FILTER(_tempOutput,(INDEX(_tempOutput,,3)=B1)*(TAKE(_tempOutput,,-1)<>"no result")),6),
     VSTACK({"DAY","DATE","MONTH","VENUE","CREW","CREW NO"},CHOOSECOLS(_output,1,2,3,4,6,5)))
```

---

**Note:** The changes you may need for the initials & month cell references as well need to change ranges accordingly as per your data.

---

As mentioned by OP in comments:

> *I have tested it and it work but a few issue when selecting initial,*
> *the "CREW NO." is wrong for other initial. Really sorry, is it*
> *possible to remove the initial selection and only use month selection?*
> *As well as the removing the header?*

---

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _BaseData, VSTACK(April:May!A2:D5),
     _BaseCrew, VSTACK(April:May!Q2:Z5),
     _BaseDataCrewN, WRAPCOLS(TOCOL(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(_BaseCrew)),LAMBDA(x,y,
       VSTACK(x,IF(_BaseCrew<>"",INDEX(_BaseData,,y),NA())))),1),2),SUM(N(_BaseCrew<>""))),
     _CrewNoCrew, TOCOL(IFS(_BaseCrew<>"",HSTACK(_BaseCrew&"|"&April!Q1:Z1)),2),
     _TempOutput, HSTACK(_BaseDataCrewN, TEXTBEFORE(_CrewNoCrew,"|"),TEXTAFTER(_CrewNoCrew,"|")),
     IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(_TempOutput,(INDEX(_TempOutput,,3)=B1)),5),"Select Month Name"))
```

---

Comment: I have tested it and it work but a few issue when selecting initial, the "CREW NO." is wrong for other initial. Really sorry, is it possible to remove the initial selection and only use month selection? As well as the removing the header?

Comment: @TK4795 but you had that `r` i.e. initial in your original formula.

Comment: It is now no longer needed as I wanted to print the whole month with all the data within that month sheet. My apologies.

Comment: @TK4795 then that is a different question. You cannot change your question.

Comment: With the header, it printed Vertically instead of Horizontally.

My apologies, I will award your answer and will ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood things correctly, you wanted to be able to select a value varying from `Januari` to `December` as well as select a crew member by it's initials from two separate drop downs.

As a result from these selections you want a report which dynamically only lists the data from selected month where the crew member's initials are mentioned in any of the crew columns. You want to return the first 4 columns values and the header value of the column where the crew member initial is found.

Then how about using this formula:

```
=LET(y, VSTACK(January:December!A2:AA99),
     m, FILTER(y,INDEX(y,,3)=C2),
     s, SEQUENCE(,10,17),
     e, FILTER(m,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(m,s),LAMBDA(r,OR(C4=r)))),
IF(OR(C2="",C4=""),
   "",
   IFERROR( HSTACK(TAKE(e,,4),
                   BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(e,s),LAMBDA(r,CONCAT(REPT("Crew "&s-16,r=C4))))),
            "No results")))
```

Where `C2` is the month selection and `C4` is the initial selection.
[image]

First all data of tabs January through December are stacked and named `y`.
Secondly `y` is filtered on the third column to equal the month selection `C2` and named `m`.
A sequence of 17 to 27 (column numbers of the different crew #'s) is created as `s`.
`e` filters the month filter `m` where row wise the selected intial `C4` is found.

Finally (if both are selected) we stack the first 4 columns of `e` and (simulate) the header value where the initials where found in each row.

(Link to sample of file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgYgS8dIx4V1ps60INA?e=lEM1RZ
I also made the initials drop down selection dependent on the month selection in this file)

Comment: This creates the report in one go, stepping over the month report. Not sure if that in between step was actually required.