# How to create a dependent validation list that depends on a list generated on another sheet with multiple catgeories?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a cell have the capability to ultimately reference data in Sheet2, adn this cell will filter the options based on the data validation selected in the cell to the left.
Please see the screenshots below.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

I have tried condensing into one sheet:

[image: Type Data List]

[image: the conditional display list]

[image: Specific part that is filtered]

^^^ So this does not work because I would need to update the list that it grabs from each time, like it just wouldn't work if I wanted something like this [image: grabbing data explained]

I've tried the naming list way under the Formulas tab and tried dependent data validation lists with the =indirect() formula, but I believe my goal is a little bit more complex.

Comment: Please reference the data validation list formula.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742215/4961700

Comment: See a live example in the file linked in the bottom of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77854605/12634230

Answer (score 0):

By using a Dummy Sheet, or some other range where spill data, you can create a spill array where you set the unique values of your table, this can be then referenced by selecting the cell where the spill starts followed by an "#" or by naming the range to something convenient (part_list --> A2#).

I'm going to show two cases where this can be applied, there are better ways but this is a good, simple way to do it.

I have created two tables "Table1" & "Table2" that contain the data you've shown in the example.

**CASE 1:**

Here I have applied a `UNIQUE` Formula in the cell "E5" to get rid of duplicates, this spill range will provide the type values for our first list located in E3 and references "E5#".

```
=UNIQUE(Table1[Type],FALSE,FALSE)
```

Afterwards I have used a Filter formula, to get an array of PartNum values that coincide with the first selected value, the resulting spill is F5 and is referenced in our F3 Data validation list "F5#". Finally the third part is a simple VLOOKUP using the PartNum as reference.

```
=FILTER(Table1[[PartNum],Table1[Type]=E2),,)
=VLOOKUP(F3, Table1[[PartNum]:[Name]], 2, FALSE)
```

[image]

**CASE 2:**
Here I decided to make a small table where you could use filters and such, therefore, by selecting a type, you would get a small summary table. This was achieved using my first `UNIQUE` Formula and Data Validation List on a cell. However, by using the `FILTER` and `INDEX` Formulas, we can create several spills with headers, which can be filtered.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Type]=E2),,2)
=INDEX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Type]=E2),,3)
=INDEX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Type]=E2),,4)
```

The final "2" is telling which column of the spill I want to show, the previous parameter (empty) tells the row you want. In this case, you can show only the fields you find relevant and also apply various types of filters

[image]

[image]

A final remark is that this is not a ListObject Table and Tables are not designed to be used with spills, think of it as range that acts like a pseudo-table which gives a visual aid to the user. Also, the named ranges will nor adapt to the resizing of a spill so beware of that.

Please make any corrections if I have missed something. Hope it helps!

Comment: I feel like I would need to update the list every time then. I updated my post and tried to implement what you're stating, but I am kind of confused on the last segment because I am not sure if I had incorporated that last part appropriately.

Comment: @weaver There is no need for list updates, I'll update my answer to better to better ilustrate my answer. Sorry for the late reply, I had a few busy days.